# What would stop a jQuery function from firing after replacing HTML on the page with similar elements?

Tags: jquery

If I have the following HTML:

```
<tr id="record_1" >
<td id="name_1"><a href="#" class="logNameAndValue">Charles Dickens</a></td><td id="value_1">A Christmas Carol</td>
</tr>
```

And another jQuery function is called to replace it with this:

```
<tr id="record_1" >
<td id="name_1"><a href="#" class="logNameAndValue">Kurt Vonnegut</a></td><td id="value_1">Slaughterhouse Five</td>
</tr>
```

After the replacement, the onClick function no longer works:

```
$('a.logNameAndValue').click( function(event){
    console.log("clicked!");
});
```

I tried moving all jQuery functions from being defined inside the `<body>` tag to the `<head>` tag but it made no difference.

I've monitored activity in the Firebug Console and Net panels and **Firebug doesn't indicate a click has taken place.**

But the `.click` works fine when the page is first loaded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('a.logNameAndValue').live('click',function(event){
    console.log("clicked!");
});
```

Since element is generated **dynamically**, the normal `click` hanlder won't work and that's where `live()` comes in.

> Description: Attach a handler to the
>   event for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now **and in the
>   future**.

Answer (score 2):

That click handler is attached to that particular element in the DOM. When you remove the original element, you remove the handler. If you use .delegate() or .live() instead, you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `.live` instead of `.click`

```
$('a.logNameAndValue').live('click', function(event){
    console.log("clicked!");
});
```